# cakePHP, page to a certain record

Tags: php, pagination, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way to open directly the page in which a record appears?

Example:

```
function index($id){
  $this->paginate = array(
    'limit'=>12,
    'page' => ????
  );
  $items = $this->Item->paginate();
  /**
    How can i calculate the page number, by the $id?
  */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got the ID, and you are auto_incrementing the ID in your database, you can count row before this ID:

```
$nbRow = $this->Item->find('count', array('conditions' => array('id <=' => $id))) ;
```

Then to find the page, you just have to divide (int division) by the number of item per page:

```
$page = ceil($nbRow / 12) ; // 12 or whatever item per page you have
```

Comment: the problem arises when he is sorting his records by a column that is not the id. He has to retrieve the sorting column from the pagination setting and use the same criterion in your count query

Comment: I can't base it on the A.I, since it's not consistent after some deletions.. @holt

Comment: yes @arilia, but in this situation the sorting is disabled, so - irrelevant.

Comment: @yossi Explain your point of view? I don't see any problem if you have  deleted row in your table since they are not counted.

Comment: @Holt why do you say that the sorting is disabled? The paginator component set the sorting column based on the query string so you can't know what field is beeing used for sorting

Comment: @arilia Not my comment :) It's a comment from the OP so I think he knows what he is doing.

Comment: @Holt - correct, false logic by me. however, the `(int)` should be `ceil()`, fix it in the example and it will be accepted. thanks